# Oracle PL/SQL REGEXP_LIKE / REGEXP_INSTR

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I require a means of checking to see if a string has the following exact pattern within it, i.e.:

```
(P)
```

Examples where this would be true is:

```
Test System (P)
```

I am not sure though how to check for cases when the string that doesn't have '(P)', i.e:

'Test System (GUI for Prof)' - in this case, this would be false but I am using REGEXP_LIKE and it actually returns TRUE.

I only want it to return True when the exact string of '(P)' exists within the search string.

How can I do this in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
REGEX_LIKE(t.column, '\(P\)')
```

[Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a great resource.

Regular [INSTR](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php) would work (Oracle 8i+):

```
WHERE INSTR(t.column, '(P)') > 0 --column contains '(P)'

WHERE INSTR(t.column, '(P)') = 0 --column does NOT contain '(P)'
```

LIKE works too:

```
WHERE t.column LIKE '%(P)%' --column contains '(P)'

WHERE t.column NOT LIKE '%(P)%' --column does NOT contain '(P)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `like`:

```
WHERE thing like '%(P)%';
```

Comment: Agree. If you are not checking for a regular expression, why use REGEXP functions

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with `REGEXP_*` functions, as you'll need to practice them anyway, and knowing regular expressions will serve you well.

They're all good answers, except for a typo in Ponies' first answer. :

The typo is that there's a **P** missing from REGEX_LIKE:

Written: `REGEX_LIKE(t.column, '\(P\)')`

**Correct: `REGEXP_LIKE(T.COLUMN, '\(P\)')`**

The '\' is an escape character that says "don't look for the symbolic meaning of the next character, but look for the literal character itself."